# How to fix the Force Close error?

Tags: java, android, forceclose

I am trying to create an application where if the button is clicked, a new activity will be shown. I am keeping to get the force close message and nothing comes handy. What can I do?

Here is the Java code:

```
package com.example.basic2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public Button myBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        myBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     Activity2.class);    
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.basic2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Someone might have a solution?

The errors that is given from the logcat is: 
 http://prntscr.com/38xjpo

Comment: Could be lots of reasons. Post the logcat and make sure that ` Activity2` is declared in your manifest.

Comment: Money says it is the lack of the declaration of Activity2 in your manifest. Good call codeMagic. Go into your manifest and add <activity android name=".Activity2" />

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, when you have an error of your app, try to post the stacktrace displayed into the LogCat. To enable LogCat: Window > Show View >  Other..., select Android then LogCat

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from a screenshot of logcat, but it looks like myBtn is null and so throws a NullPointerException when you try to set the onClickListener. Can you check it?

The exception is coming from line 21 in your source file.

Comment: myBtn can't be null because I am comparing it to the view that I have found with the findViewById().. I have tried to manage the inner text but nothing comes handy. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If you check myBtn != null before setting the onclick listener does it fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change this, instead of `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     Activity2.class);`
try this `Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);`

Comment: It doesn't help so much, because whenever I try to create a new application, with even any implementation of new intent I am getting the force close message. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`button1` is in the fragment layout and not in the activity layout (evidence: `tools:context="com.example.basic2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"`). It's not in the view hierarchy in activity `onCreate()` and you cannot find it with `findViewById()`.

Move the `button1` code to `PlaceholderFragment` `onCreateView()` and call `findViewById()` there on the freshly inflated view, e.g.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(...);
myBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
myBtn.setOnClickListener(...);
return rootView;
```

Comment: I have added the onCreateView() but it wasn't helpful, I am still getting the force close message. Any other ideas? Thanks.